# How to save gameobject as prefab or save scene for save system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load

My game has building and designing system. I want to save gameobject as prefab or save scene because for example chair is child of home_gameobject. If i save home_gameobject as prefab just instantiate home_gameobject on load.

If not possible, how can I do what I have in mind (save & load) ?

Answer (score 1):

For save system, you don't need to save prefab or scene.
You can save only attributes of these gameobjects for example position, rotation, scale and so on.
So you can save it to json file or to database and can also load from it and set attributes to the right gameobjects.
I hope it will work on your project.

Comment: I thought about it too, but I wanted to ask if there is such a method, because it would be easier. Thanks